# How to save PictureBox.Image to file?

Tags: c#, bitmap, picturebox

I use the following to write jpgImage to a PictureBox.Image.

```
var jpgImage = new Byte[jpgImageSize];
...
pictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(jpgImage));
```

and I can use the following to write a byte array to a file

```
using (var bw =
    new BinaryWriter(File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create,
        FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)))
{
    bw.Write(jpgImage);
}
```

but how can I get the jpgImage byte array from the PictureBox.Image so I can write it to the file?
IOW: how do I reverse the following to get the byte array from the PictureBox.Image?

```
pictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(jpgImage));
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this

```
pictureBox.Image.Save(@"Path",ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: i have used this
 PicBox.Image.Save(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    
there is picture in the picbox but the saved picture is full black

Comment: What path is like  pbImg.Image.Save(@"D:\Kishan\ki.jpg");

Answer (score 7):

You may use,

```
pictureBox.Image.Save(stream,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Example:

```
 System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
 pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
 byte[] ar = new byte[ms.Length];
 ms.Write(ar, 0, ar.Length);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use below code for save into custom location

```
using (SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog() {Filter = @"PNG|*.png"})
                    {
                        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                            pictureBox.Image.Save(saveFileDialog.FileName);
                        }
                    }
```