# Z-Index of Drawing Rectangle C#

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have an application which uses the mouse to free-draw a rectangle on a picbox image. However the rectangle only shows up behind the picbox, rather than on top of it. Is there a property i can set which can fix this? (show rect on top of picbox image rather than behind it). Here is the code:

```
   System.Drawing.Graphics picboxGraphics;
    bool mDown = false;
    int mouseX;
    int mouseY;

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mDown = true;
        mouseX = e.X;
        mouseY = e.Y;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mDown == true)
        {
            this.Refresh();
            Pen drawPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 5);
            int width = e.X - mouseX, height = e.Y - mouseY;
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(mouseX, mouseY, width * Math.Sign(width), height * Math.Sign(height));
            picboxGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
            picboxGraphics.DrawRectangle(drawPen, rect);
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mDown = false;
    }
```

Comment: You could simply make a bitmap and draw on the bitmap then set the source of the picture box. Now the content of the picture box being actually set to an image it will always show over it's container.

Comment: I have not worked with bitmaps before but this may help when trying to save the modified image

Comment: search to create graphics from bitmap. very easy it's done same way your sample code is done except of doing picturebox.draw() it's like MyBitmap.draw(). You can use the Class `Bitmap` or simply `Image` and they can both save to stream or file directly. they are in `System.Image` if i recall

Comment: Using CreateGraphics() is always wrong.  Using the CreateGraphics method of the *form* instead of the picturebox is especially wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You creating graphics from form which is behind the picbox
you can create graphics from picbox's image and draw someting. But if you want layer system you can draw your thins on an transparent image and combine them. with this vay you can make an undo or delete layer system.

Answer (score -1):

There are several problems in your code: dispose, global variable and wrong control to create graphics from. Make it this way:

```
using(var graphics = (sender as Control).CreateGraphics())
    graphics.DrawRectangle(drawPen, rect);
```

But honestly, you have to organize it differently (assuming you are going to mimik Paint):

- create new object (when mouse is down)
- in `Paint` event draw object (if any)
- during mouse move event, update *edited* object properties and call `Invalidate`
- when you minimize/restore your form, the object will be still there (while in your example, it will get lost).

You can support `List` of objects to have storage for many rectangles and add history support (as TC Alper Tokcan answer suggesting) to at least `Undo` last object.

Comment: The code works fine to draw rectangle on pic box. I need to somehow convert all to bitmap so that I can save the modified Image. Is this possible without rearranging the entire application as you are suggesting>?

Comment: It sounds like a new *question*, if you use search, then [...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845720/how-to-save-picturebox-image-to-file)