# Paint on a panel image and save changes

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, paint

I have a panel with a background image set that I want to be able to draw on and save changes as an image file. I managed to complete the painting part with 'panel1.CreateGraphics', however this does not allow you to save whatever you've painted on top of the image (if you minimize the windows the paintings disappear).

How can I paint on the panel (and its bkground image) and then save changes?

Note: I have asked a couple of similar questions with no definitive answers as I don't think people have grasped what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Did you try to use the `Bitmap` class with a `PictureBox`?

Comment: Yes that was my first attempt, but I need to use a panel now although ti shouldn't really make a different. Its just getting the paint to apply itself to the panel within a bitmap

Comment: You can't use CreateGraphics().  Paint on the BackgroundImage instead with Graphics.FromImage().  Call the Panel's Invalidate() method when you're done painting so the user can see it.

Comment: Graphics.FromImage isn't a method of 'panel' ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Save modified image in panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843369/c-sharp-save-modified-image-in-panel)